# how to get parameters in php page with ajax and $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .post

actually i'm new to web and php,
i'm building a website,
i would like to introduce chat session there but, when the user click the insert button that's not working (failing to pass the paramerts to another page)

Help me out...!!!

here is the code

chat_page.php

```
<input type="text" id="txtmsg" name="txtmsg" size="25"> <input type="button" value="send" onclick="sndmsg()">
```

jscript.js

```
function sndmsg() {
    msg=document.getElementById('txtmsg').value;
    $.post("insert.php",{u:un,m:msg},function(){ });
    document.getElementById('txtmsg').value=""; 
}
```

insert.php

```
include("connec.php");
$chatmsg=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['m']);
$uname=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['u']);
echo $chatmsg;
echo $uname;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mdi_chat_msg`(`uname`, `chatmsg` ) VALUES ( '$uname','$chatmsg')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Check your developers console and see if you find any errors..

Comment: check your console and network section to trace problem.

Comment: @user3386779 form? why? He is use ajax ?

Comment: Have you declared the variables `un` and `msg` anywhere in your JS code? (something along the lines of `un='user'; msg = $('#txtmsg').val();` ?

Comment: please do not use mysql extension anymore, as it's [deprecated the the moment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and is going to be [removed in PHP7 completely](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7)

Comment: refer the points given by @Mahdi Parsa

Comment: Now i got the answer, its the problem with the request values. Thanks to everyone. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is un in jscript.js. Maybe, that parameter is unknown.

```
$.post("insert.php",{u:un,m:msg},function(){ });
```

You should declare un and msg variables;

```
var un, msg;
```

Comment: Actually I haven't assigned the values.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have declare  and change the type="submit" instead type="button"  you cant use the word msg as variable and cant pass the js value in ajax  and check un variable.

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id="txtmsg" name="txtmsg" size="25"> <input type="submit" value="send" onclick="sndmsg()">
</form>


<script>
    function sndmsg() {
        msg1=$("#txtmsg").val();
        $.post("insert.php",{u:un,m:msg},function(){ });
        document.getElementById('txtmsg').value=""; 
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: { u: un,m:msg1},
    });
</script>
```

Comment: form? why? He is use ajax ? why you think can solve problem with this solution?